# indexOf - search value in a string, if not, do something

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have a formula:

Total_ID = id1,id2,id3,...,id10

If myid included in Array “total_ID”, do AAA;

I use:

```
if (( total_ID.split(",").indexOf(myid.toString()) && (myid !=””))
{AAA}
```

How can I change my above formula for the following condition?

If myid is **not** included in Total_ID, do AAA.

Comment: Try with `if (( total_ID.split(",").indexOf(myid.toString()) >= 0 && (myid !=""))`

Comment: Did you check what `indexOf()` returns when a value is not found in the array? Check for that value and you're done.

Comment: `array,includes()` seems appropriate for the test.  The else block of an if statement is where the **not** logic goes.  Or negate the if condition with `!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether `indexOf()` returns `-1` or not.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or **`-1`** if it is not present.

```js
Total_ID = 'id1,id2,id3,id10';
myid = 'id4';
if (Total_ID.split(",").indexOf(myid) == -1){
  console.log('not found');
}
```

Alternatively,  you can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which simplifies it:

```js
Total_ID = 'id1,id2,id3,id10';
myid = 'id4';
if (!Total_ID.split(",").includes(myid)){
  console.log('not found');
}
```